# influxdb's field type equivalent in prometheus

Tags: monitoring, influxdb, prometheus

influxdb's data schema supports fields and tags. tags are indexed and fields are not.

prometheus support labels and float64 value.

Mapping between prometheus and influxdb data is as follows:

labels : tags

float64 : a default field

My use case is monitoring batch jobs having auxillary metadata (processid,logfilepath etc.). I dont want these attributes to be indexed.

How do I model these attributes in prometheus ? If I use labels for the same, its going to explode memory usage (label indexing), since its values are not enumerated.

Whats the best way to take care above attributes in prometheus ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the processid is a number, you can expose it as a gauge.
For strings you can expose them as a label on a 1-valued gauge, such as is done for [software versions](https://www.robustperception.io/exposing-the-software-version-to-prometheus/).

Comment: Thanks @brian-brazil for your prompt response. I have few doubts: 1. my batch jobs are about a million / day. So, essentially, I shall be publishing job_info{jobid=<JOBID>, metadata1="v1", ..., "metadataN"="vN" } 1 . a million times/day where lable combination are going to differ for each million. wouldnt it affect the memory consumption for prometheus, since it indexes the labels ? Thanks alot for your kind help.

Comment: That sounds more like event logging than metrics, as we expect batch jobs to maybe run once an hour. You probably want something like ELK, as what you would be exposing to Prometheus for something like that would be the total number of jobs ran, not individual job details.

Comment: Thanks @brian-brazil. I am not sure if it is event logging indeed. job auxillary properties/metadata is not exactly like event logging. I have gone through influxdb fields concept. It seems to fit in, nicely. Thanks alot for your feedback. we ll use prometheus for which its meant to be

Comment: That volume of batch jobs is what makes it event logging. The properties/metadata is kinda event logging - but you can make it work as per my answer.

Comment: Hmmm ... I think I would evaluate other options. looks like prometheus is not optimized for my use case.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't sound like Prometheus is right for this particular part of your problem.